# Animated (shrinking) Resizing Header On Scroll in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "50%";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
(function ($) {
    // Instantiate MixItUp:
    // $('Container').mixItUp();
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
    $(".sidenav a").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var datanew= this.href;
        var str2 = '.html';
        if(datanew.indexOf(str2) != -1){
            window.location.href = datanew;
        }else{
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top}, 
            900, function(){
                alert(window.location);
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(window).click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('div#mySidenav').length === 0 && $(event.target).closest('.menu-icon').length === 0) {
    closeNav()
  }
})
```

```css
#section0{
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url(
https://images7.alphacoders.com/669/thumb-1920-669739.jpg);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 background-position:center top;
 
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ef4f50;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    /*max-height: 551px;*/
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.menu-icon
{
    color: #114576;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.menu{
    min-height: 100px;
}
/*#banner{
    background: url(.././img/banner/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
}*/
.logo-name{
    font-size: 65px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    color: #FFB03B;
}

.bannertext{
    margin-top: 80px;   
}

.bannerelements{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.mahaGov{
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

/* button custom style */ 

.btn-round{
border-radius: 17px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 8px 25px;
    border: 0 none;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top:25px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.btn-danger {
    background: #ef4f50;
    color: #ffffff;
}
 
.btn-danger:hover, .btn-danger:focus, .btn-danger:active, .btn-danger.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-danger {
    background: #c03233;
}
 
.btn-danger:active, .btn-danger.active {
    background: #c03233;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.logo{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#buildingblocks{
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

.text-color{
    color :#114576;
}

.ptext-size{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text-white{
    color :#ffffff;
}

/* Custom font effects */

h1{
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section align-center" id="section0">  
  <div class="heading">
   <header id="header">               
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="index.html" class="sidenavtext">Home</a>
          <a href="about.html" class="sidenavtext">About Us</a>
          <a href="whatwedo.html" class="sidenavtext">What We Do</a>
          <a href="getinvolved.html" class="sidenavtext">Get Involved</a>
          <a href="contactus.html" class="sidenavtext">Contact Us</a>
        </div>

        <div class="control">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2796/metro_uinvert_dock/128/microsoft_new_logo.png" class="pull-left img-responsive logo" alt="SAF Logo">  
          </div>                            
          <div class="col-md-8">                                
            <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
            <span onclick="openNav()" class="pull-right menu-icon">☰</span>  
            <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-round donate" id="donate">DONATE NOW</button>
          </div>
        </div>                
      </header>                
   <div class="col-md-12 home-col12">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="bannertext bannerelements">
            <h1>45% of youth</h1>
            <h1>make the wrong</h1>
            <h1>career and</h1>
            <h1>life choices.</h1>         
          </div>
          <div class="bannerelements">
            <br>
            <p class="text-color ptext-size">The Right Education can change that</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-round" style="margin-left: 40px;">BE A PART OF CHANGE</button>    
          </div>
          <div class="row bannerelements mahaGov">                    
            <img src="assets/img/home/banner/mahaGov1.png" class="pull-left img-responsive" alt="Govt. of Maharashtra Logo">    
          </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
        </div>
      </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

hello this code is for the menu-bar as well as section.my website is divided in sections.each section is full page height 100% for all screen.i want to set my header fixed on top but i want to shrink my menu or Resize my menu on Scroll of Page.as in this link "http://trungk18.github.io/Resizing-Header-On-Scroll/"

Comment: Hi, 
Sorry I am little bit confused what you really want to ask because on code snippet you something different but on link you shown different . so please clear

Comment: i want that effect for my menu.i have posted my menu-bar code